# How to copy the complete folder structure one location to another location include all files and sub folders

Tags: client-object-model

I have folder structure like in Shared documents/East using CSOM and C#
Main Folder
  Folder1
  Folder2
     File1
     File2

I have to copy all folders with files to Shared documents/West
....

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in method in SharePoint CSOM API for copying Folder with Files from one location into another.

The following solution demonstrates how to copy files from source folder into destination folder:

```
public static class FolderExtensions
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Copy files 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="folder">Source Folder</param>
    /// <param name="folderUrl">Target Folder Url</param>
    public static void CopyFilesTo(this Folder folder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var ctx = (ClientContext)folder.Context;
        if (!ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))
        {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }
        ctx.Load(folder, f => f.Files, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.Folders);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        //Ensure target folder exists
        ctx.Web.EnsureFolder(folderUrl.Replace(ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, string.Empty));
        foreach (var file in folder.Files)
        {
            var targetFileUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
            file.CopyTo(targetFileUrl,true);
        }
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var subFolder in folder.Folders)
        {
            var targetFolderUrl = subFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
            subFolder.CopyFilesTo(targetFolderUrl);
        }
    }
}

static class WebExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures whether the folder exists   
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Folder EnsureFolder(this Web web, string folderUrl)
    {
        return EnsureFolderInternal(web.RootFolder, folderUrl);
    }


    private static Folder EnsureFolderInternal(Folder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var ctx = parentFolder.Context;
        var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var folderName = folderNames[0];
        var folder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
        ctx.Load(folder);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        if (folderNames.Length > 1)
        {
            var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
            return EnsureFolderInternal(folder, subFolderUrl);
        }
        return folder;
    }
}
```

Key points:

- allows to ensure whether target folder(s) exists
- In case of nested folders, its structure is preserved while copying files

**Usage**

```
var srcFolderUrl = "/news/pages"; //News site with Pages library
var destFolderUrl = "/news/archive/pages"; //News archive sub site with Pages library
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{      
    var sourceFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(srcFolderUrl);
    sourceFolder.CopyFilesTo(destFolderUrl);
}
```

Comment: This code unfortunately doesn't make any sense.  GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl only works in the context of the web you are trying to get a folder from.  folderUrl.Replace(ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, string.Empty) replaces destinationFolderUrl to gibberish. You can not "CopyTo" to another sub site. Have you tried this code before posting?

Answer (score 4):

```
string siteUrl = "your site url";
    string sourceDirectory = "your source folder";
    string destinationDirectory = "/Shared documents/West";

    using (SPSite currSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb currWeb = currSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            MoveFolder(currWeb, sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory);
        }
    }

    //Move all folders and subfolder
    public void MoveFolder(SPWeb sourceWeb, string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory)
    {
        SPFolder srcFolder  = sourceWeb.GetFolder(sourceDirectory);
        if (srcFolder.Exists)
        {
            SPDocumentLibrary docLib = srcFolder.DocumentLibrary;
            SPFolderCollection oFolder = srcFolder.SubFolders;
            SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
            oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
            oQuery.Folder = oFolder.Folder;
            oQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
            SPListItemCollection collListItems = docLib.GetItems(oQuery);
            string newdestinationFolderPath = destinationDirectory;
            //Move the root folder with files
            MoveSingleFolder(sourceWeb, sourceDirectory, newdestinationFolderPath);

            newdestinationFolderPath = destinationDirectory + "/" + srcFolder.Name;
            //Move the subfolders with files
            foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
            {
                MoveSingleFolder(sourceWeb, item.Url, newdestinationFolderPath);
            }
            // Delete the root folder
            DeleteSourceFolder(sourceWeb, sourceDirectory);
        }

    }

    //Move single folder
    private void MoveSingleFolder(SPWeb srcWeb, string sourceFolderPath, string destinationFolderPath)
    {
        SPFolder srcFolder = srcWeb.GetFolder(sourceFolderPath);
        if (srcFolder.Exists)
        {
            string srcFolderName = srcFolder.Name;
            SPFolder dstFolder = srcWeb.GetFolder(destinationFolderPath);
            if (dstFolder.Exists)
            {
                //create the folder
                SPFolder newFolder = dstFolder.SubFolders.Add(srcFolderName);
                    SPListItem newFolderItem = (SPListItem)newFolder.Item;
                    newFolderItem.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified].ReadOnlyField = false;
                    newFolderItem.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified_x0020_By].ReadOnlyField = false;
                    newFolderItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified] = srcFolder.Item["Modified"];
                    newFolderItem["Modified By"] = srcFolder.Item["Modified By"];
                    newFolderItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
                    newFolderItem.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified].ReadOnlyField = true;
                    newFolderItem.ParentList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified_x0020_By].ReadOnlyField = true;

            }
            MoveFolderItems(srcWeb, sourceFolderPath, destinationFolderPath + "/" + srcFolderName);
        }
    }

    //Move folder items
    private void MoveFolderItems(SPWeb sourceWeb, string sourceFolderPath, string destinationFolderPath)
    {
        SPFolder srcFolder = sourceWeb.GetFolder(sourceFolderPath);
        int fileCount = srcFolder.Files.Count;
        while (fileCount > 0)
        {
            SPFile sourceFile = sourceWeb.GetFile(srcFolder.Files[0].Url);
            object modifiedOn = sourceFile.Item["Modified"];
            object modifiedBy = sourceFile.Item["Modified By"];

            sourceFile.MoveTo(destinationFolderPath + "/" + sourceFile.Name, true);

            fileCount--;

            SPListItem dstItem = (SPListItem)sourceFile.Item;
            dstItem.ParentList.Fields["Modified"].ReadOnlyField = false;
            dstItem.ParentList.Fields["Modified By"].ReadOnlyField = false;
            dstItem["Modified"] = modifiedOn;
            dstItem["Modified By"] = modifiedBy;
            dstItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion(); //updates the item without creating another version of the item
            dstItem.ParentList.Fields["Modified"].ReadOnlyField = true;
            dstItem.ParentList.Fields["Modified By"].ReadOnlyField = true;
        }
    }

    //Delete the folder
    private void DeleteSourceFolder(SPWeb srcWeb, string sourceFolderPath)
    {
        SPFolder srcFolder = srcWeb.GetFolder(sourceFolderPath);
        if (srcFolder.Exists)
        {
            if (srcFolder.Files.Count == 0) //Delete only after moving
            {
                SPFolder srcRootFolder = srcFolder.ParentFolder;
                srcRootFolder.SubFolders.Delete(srcFolder.Url);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The OP is asking about CSOM solution

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help for your problems :

```
public static void CopyFiles(string url, string listTitle, string srcFolder,string destFolder)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        //context.Credentials = credentials;


        var srcList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}", srcFolder);
        var srcItems = srcList.GetItems(qry);
        context.Load(srcItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i.FileSystemObjectType, i => i["FileRef"], i => i.File));
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var item in srcItems)
        {
            switch (item.FileSystemObjectType)
            {
                case FileSystemObjectType.Folder:
                    var destFolderUrl = ((string)item["FileRef"]).Replace(srcFolder,destFolder);
                    CreateFolder(context.Web,destFolderUrl);
                    break;
                case FileSystemObjectType.File:
                    var destFileUrl = item.File.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(srcFolder, destFolder);
                    item.File.CopyTo(destFileUrl, true);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
} 

private static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string folderUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Folder Url could not be empty");

    var folder = web.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
    web.Context.Load(folder);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    return folder;
}
```

Usage :

```
CopyFiles("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/", "Shared Documents", "Expense", "Expense 2015");
```