# How to copy documents from 1 folder to another within same library in SP2013 using VS code?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, document-library, visual-studio-2013

I want to copy documents from one folder to another folder within same library in SharePoint 2013 using visual studio code. The source document, source and destination path values are given through excel sheet.

Comment: Do you know how to read excel file using c#

Comment: No. It will be useful if you teach how to do. Dipongkor.

Comment: Ok. see this to read excel using c# http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-of

And copy file folder to folder 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/117883/21421

Comment: Hey, Did my link help you???

Comment: No. It's not working.

Comment: So how did you try that? Show your code in your question