# Creating folder recursively using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to copy list items and folders from `source list` to `destination list` using csom.

Till now I am able to copy items and folder in the list but not able to copy items and folders inside the folder. I want to make it a `recursive call` where it should check inside each folder that if it is a contains a folder then add that folder in target list else check for items.

Please tell me how to change the structure of my code to make it a recursive call.

My code structure is:-

```
foreach (ListItem items in listItemsFrom)
 {
    if(folder)
    {
    copy folder
    }
    else
    {
    copy items
    }
}
```

How would I write a recursive function for the same?

Comment: This link may give some reference: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97116/how-to-copy-the-complete-folder-structure-one-location-to-another-location-inclu

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are looking for the below code. You can check it.

http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.no/2011/07/c-copy-files-and-folders-recursively.html